# initializing a member variable instead of an instance variable

Tags: java, arraylist

I have been having issues with a class named `arrayList` that represents a list of objects and supports random access to its objects via a numeric position index.

After working out the issues with `toString()` and `size()`, I encountered an issue where I am not initializing my member array; only init'ing a locale variable. However I was under the impression that a modification I made should have solved the issue.

```
public Object get(int a) {
    if (a < 0 || a >= logicalSize) {
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Positions must be from position 0 to position "+
                                            (logicalSize - 1));
    }
    else {
        return array[a];
    }
}
```

But shouldn't my declaration of 
`private static Object[] array = new Object[5];` solve that?

I am currently getting an error throwing my exception, telling me my position must be from 0 to -1, suggesting it isn't created.

Full Code:

```
public class Tester  {
        public static void main(String [] args)
        {
            arrayList a1, a2;
            a1 = new arrayList();
            a2 = new arrayList(5);
            a2.size();
            System.out.println(a1.toString());
            //System.out.println(a2.toString());
        }
    }

public class arrayList
{
    private int logicalSize;
    private static Object[] array = new Object[0];
    private Object[] original;
    private Object removedElement;

    public arrayList()
    {
        Object[] array = new Object[]{null,null,null,null,null}; 
    }

    public arrayList(int i)
    {
        logicalSize = i;
        Object[] array = new Object[logicalSize - 1];
    }

    public arrayList(Object[] array)
    {
       logicalSize = array.length;
       Object[] copyArray = array;
    }

    public String toString(Object[] array)
    {
       String str = " ";

       for(int a = 0; a < logicalSize; a++)
       {
          str = str + array[a];
       }

       str = str + "\nSize: " + size();
      return str;
   }  

   public int size()
   {
       int length = array.length;
       return length;
   }
}
```

Much Thanks, Packerfan504

Comment: Why is `array` static?

Comment: also, this is confusing because Class names should be capitalized

Comment: Static was removed, and class names are capitalized but some problems still persist. See @Abbé Résinas answer lower for more issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should follow Java conventions for class names. It should start with a capital letter and go CamelCase.

`array` should certainly **not** be `static`. When you declare a member `static`, it means that it is shared between all instances

In the Constructors, you set *local* variables instead of the member.

```
 // remove Object[] in front
 array = new Object[]{null,null,null,null,null};
```

The constructor from an array does not set the member `array`.

```
public arrayList(Object[] array)
{
   logicalSize = array.length;
   //Object[] copyArray = array;
   this.array = array;
}
```

This does not do any copy: the member reference the array passed as a parameter. I you want some kind of "copy constructor", you need to actually instantiate a new array and copy each element. Or use [`Arrays.copyOf()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf(T[],%20int)).

You should *overide* `toString()` method from `java.langObject` with right signature (why pass the array as a parmeter?). All classes in Java extends implicitly `Object` class.

You should differentiate the `Object[]` array size  - which is the number of potenital slots you have before needing an increase of the array, and the *logical* size that reflects the number of elements you have put in your array. Here you set the logical size to array.length, thats just redundant information.

---

**EDIT** Additional advices

In the constructor with the size as parameter, you create an array of (logicalSize-1). Why?

In the default constructor, you don't initialize `logicalSize`, it is then set to `0`. It's ok for me, but then, why do you set it to `i` in the constructor with a size as parameter?
Then it's normal that in the `a1.get(0)`:

```
if (a < 0 || a >= logicalSize) {...}
```

is `true` and throw the exception.

I would recommend that you clarify the role of `logicalSize` which is (for me) the number of actual objects in the `ArrayList`. Note that in your test, you don't put *anything* in your array yet. Even if you have an internal array that can hold 5 Objects, until you `add(...)` something, calling `get(0)` should throw an exception.

Comment: An updated version of my Code still doesn't adress the issue for the Default Constructor, but does for the ArrayList(int i) constructor. I am unsure of how I should correct this.

New Code:
http://pastebin.com/sfUeCXG1

Comment: Ok, I see several pbs. I will add an edit to my answer.

Comment: after edit: Shouldn't get(0) return a null value? I was under the impression it would bring a null and not throw an exception.

Comment: As I said in the edit, in your test, `logicalSize` is equal to 0, then the condition for get(0) is true and this trow the exception.

Answer (score 0):

You have a class static variable

```
private static Object[] array
```

and in your constructor you are creating a local variable array;

ie doing this

```
Object[] array
```

is again going to create a local variable for that function.

since you have declared it Object[] again its going to be a variable within the constructor scope.

Comment: I am confused still. I removed the static portion from the variable yet it still is providing the same error. As is changing it from public to private. How do I make it so it is no longer a purely local variable? I Changed it to 

`private int logicalSize;
    private Object[] array = new Object[5];
    private Object[] original;
    private Object removedElement;
    public ArrayList()
    {
        array = new Object[5]; 
        
        
    }`